# Query not returning all the rows using inner join

Tags: sqlite, inner-join

```
SELECT table1.* , table2.Value 
FROM table1  
INNER JOIN  table2 
ON table1.id = table2.id 
WHERE table2.Label = "Currency"
```

This is the query. I need to return the values even if `Label = currency` does not exists.
i.e., I need to return all rows of table1 with unique id. If table2 has currency then the currency value should be taken else empty value should return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using OUTER JOIN like this:

```
SELECT table1.* , table2.Value 
FROM table1 
LEFT JOIN table2 
ON table1.id = table2.id 
AND table2.Label = "Currency"
```

Comment: Thanks @Aziz Shaikh . I should not have used where at table2.Label = "Currency". It worked

Answer (score 1):

It *sounds* like you want something along these lines.

```
SELECT table1.* , table2.Value 
FROM table1 
left join table2 on table1.id = table2.id
```

I'm assuming that table2.value is the currency value you're talking about.

Edit your question, and paste CREATE TABLE statements for more and better answers.

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
SELECT table1.* , table2.Value FROM table1 left outer join table2 on table1.id = table2.id where table2.Label = "Currency"
```